# Why does Flex say this is an "unrecognized rule"?

Tags: regex, flex-lexer

In the following:

```
space           ([ \t\f\r])+         
opt_space       ([ \t\f\r])*         
cpp             ^{opt_space}#{opt_space} 
word            [A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]*
arg_macro       {cpp}define{space}{word}
/*arg_macro       ^{opt_space}#{opt_space}define{space}{word}*/

%%
{arg_macro}     ;
%%
```

I get an error message

```
test.l:9: unrecognized rule
```

If I uncomment the second version of `arg_macro` and comment the first one, the error message goes away.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the `^` from the cpp definition, and place it in the arg_macro definition, then it's happy.

```
space           ([ \t\f\r])+
opt_space       ([ \t\f\r])*
cpp             {opt_space}#{opt_space}
word            [A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]*
arg_macro       ^{cpp}define{space}{word}
```

Comment: OK, thanks; is there some kind of reason for that or did you find it by trial and error?

Comment: I was playing around to find the actual problem sub-part. But I then went reading of the flex man page, etc. There is conflicting notes, on one page I read that you can only ^ at the beginning on the string are interpreted as line-start anchors, otherwise it's just the token. I assume that flex thinks it's invalid to nest a start of line token after the start of line, thus the definition with that anchor inside is not valid for other token expansion. This is based on the wording of the error, it implies the cpp definintion does not exists. Would have to read the code to know more.

Comment: Ok, reading the gnu flex code: start line rules, seem to get placed in a different list from the other rules, and when resolving the named symbols, it looks up the second list.

Comment: Some of it was at the end of this page: http://flex.sourceforge.net/manual/Patterns.html#Patterns

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful for me. It seems like a weakness of flex. Thanks again.