# Flex "Unrecognized Error"

Tags: c, regex, flex-lexer

While writing a token generator in flex I ran into this annoying error:
"Unrecognized Rule"

My code is:

```
/* Keywords */

TYPE        int|double|bool|char
LOGICAL     if|else|for|foreach|do|while|switch|return
MACROWORD   import|define|ifndef|endif|elseif|udef
MACRO       "#"{MACROWORD}

KEYWORD     {TYPE}|{LOGICAL}|{MACRO}

/* Literals */

DIGIT       [0-9]
DIGITS      {DIGIT}+
OPT_FRAC    ("."{DIGITS})?
OPT_EXP     (E(+|-){DIGITS})?

NUMBER      {DIGITS}{OPT_FRAC}{OPT_EXP}

LETTER      [a-zA-Z]

/* Identifier */

ID          {LETTER}({LETTER}|{DIGIT})*

/* Operators */

OPERATOR    "+"|"-"|"*"|"/"|"^"|"=""="|"<""="|">""="|">"|"<"|"!""=""

%%

{KEYWORD}   printf("(Keyword, %s)\n", yytext);

{NUMBER}    printf("(Numeric Literal, %s)", yytext);

{ID}    printf("(Identifier, %s)", yytext);

{OPERATOR}  printf("(Operator, %s", yytext);

[ \n\t]     /* Ignore Whitespace */

"{"         printf("(L Bracket, %s)", yytext);

"}"         printf("(R Bracket, %s)", yytext);

"("         printf("(L Parens, %s)", yytext);

")"         printf("(R Parens, %s", yytext);

";"         printf("(Semicolon, %s", yytext);

%%

main()
{
    yylex();
}
```

Sadly, this only results in:

"Scanner.lex:39: unrecognized rule" repeated **19 times** followed by one instance of:

"Scanner.lex:43: unrecognized rule"

Line 39 is:

```
{NUMBER}    printf("(Numeric Literal, %s)", yytext);
```

and Line 43 is:

```
{OPERATOR}  printf("(Operator, %s", yytext);
```

I hunted around the internet and found [this answer also on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243011/why-does-flex-say-this-is-an-unrecognized-rule) among others which suggested adding "^" to the beginning of the definition lines so I changed line 39 references (NUMBER) to:

```
NUMBER    ^{DIGITS}{OPT_FRAC}{OPT_EXP}
```

Which did absolutely nothing.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's freaking out because the `+` in OPT_EXP doesn't have anything to `+`.  (It's an RE `+`, not a literal plus sign.)

Your OPERATOR definition has one too many double-quotes.

Comment: Oops! didn't see that about OPT_EXP.  Also for the too many double quotes how do you fix that/what's the correct syntax for which I said "=""=" ?

Comment: Ah, you can use "==" just fine (I use too much C++ and assumed " in Flex was like ' in C/C++)

Answer (score 0):

```
OPT_EXP     ([Ee][-+]{DIGITS})?
OPERATOR1   [-+*/=^><]
OPERATOR2   ==|<=|>=|==|!=
```

If we used just one definition for operator would have a problem. The reason is that if the flex sees `<=` what will it match it as? as a `<` and then an `=` or as a `<=` all togeather?. I don't think lex supports lookahead. For this reason, I decided to split `OPERATOR` into two definitions `OPERATOR1` and `OPERATOR2`. Then in the rules section you have **2 rules**

```
{OPERATOR2}  printf("(Operator, %s", yytext);
{OPERATOR1}  printf("(Operator, %s", yytext);
```

We know that lex will preffer the longest matching rule so in the case of `<=` the `{OPERATOR2}` rule will trigger

- Note 1: When I put `-` as the 1st character in the character class eg `[-+*/]` it's treated as a regular character not the special character indicating range. `[+-*/]` for example would be wrong as `-` between `+` and `*` means all characters between `+` and `*`.
- Note 2: I made sure that `^` was not the 1st character in a character class because `^` as the 1st character in the character class means negation. `[^0-9]` for example means match every character except for a number.